# Running a R script to Update a Database

Tags: r, database

I have written a script in R that calculates a specific value for each of the S&P500 stocks. I would like to run this script every five minutes during trading hours and have the script upload the values to an online database.

I don't know anything about IT. I was thinking to run the script on AWS and have the script upload a SQL database or an AWS version of a SQL server every five minutes.

Do you guys have any ideas about how I should approach this problem? or any other methodologies I could use.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't know of any StackExchange sites that are intended to be used as complete *tutorials* or *lesson plans*, and SO is no exception. While many answers do have sufficient detail to be useful as a mini-howto or such, I believe that that is the exception. And asking for that much is off-topic, please see [help/on-topic].

Comment: As r2evans stated, this question is a little too broad. However, I would like to turn your attention to the dplyr/dbplyr/DBI/odbc libraries, which can interface with many databases, MySQL and SQLite included as some examples. Look [here](https://db.rstudio.com) to get started.

Comment: Does it have to be a database?  If this is going to be challenging for you, then you could start out by e.g. appending the entries to a text file to get you up and running.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go the AWS route with a database then there are any number of ways to achieve this, but here is an outline of a fairly straightforward approach.

1. Launch a database.  See e.g. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Welcome.html.
2. Launch an EC2 instance.  See e.g. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/concepts.html.
3. Set up a cron job to launch your R script every 5 minutes during business hours from the EC2 instance.  See e.g. https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/.
4. Use an R package such as dplyr/dbplyr/DBI/odbc as suggested by @rpolicastro to connect to and write data to the database.

I'm glossing over a lot of complication in setting up the system in AWS, but hopefully this can get you started.  Also, if you really care about ensuring that you never miss any data timepoints then you may either need to set up some kind of redundancy systems, or code in the ability to look backwards in time and fill in the missing timepoints.